# MVC Database Model Dynamic Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design

He guys, so I need a little help with my database model for an mvc project I am working on.

Here is the situation:

I have a table called dbo.Clients that has the columns ClientName, PlanName, PlanPrice, PlanStartDate, PlanEndDate, and IsArchived.

For the fields ClientName, and IsArchived are only going to have one value in them that is subject to change. However, each client will have multiple PlanName, PlanPrice, PlanStartDate, and PlanEndDate values.

I have a ClientModel, ClientViewModel, ClientRepository, ClientService, and ClientController set up that successfully puts values into the database from the view.

The problem:

The way that I have done this is that I can only use one value for PlanName, PlanPrice, PlanStartDate, and PlanEndDate. For example lets say a client has bought Plan 1 and Plan 2 but I cannot store more than 1 plan.

What I want to do is make another table called Plans but I'm not quite sure how to use that in the MVC way to storing multiple values per client.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC. You need a second table (say) `Plans` with fields `ID` (PK), `ClientID` (FK to Clients table), `Name`, `Price`, `StartDate` and `EndDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two tables. One will be a client master named something like `Clients` with the Columns `Id`, `ClientName` and `IsArchived`.

The other table will be something like `ClientPlans` with the columns `ClientId, PlanName, PlanPrice, PlanStartDate, PlanEndDate`

Ensure there's a Foreign Key relation between the `Id` in the `Clients` table and the `ClientId` in the `ClientPlans` table.

This can be refactored further to have a separate table for `Plans` (`Id,PlanName, PlanPrice, PlanStartDate, PlanEndDate`) and a transaction table called `ClientPlans` containing `ClientId` and `PlanId` with the appropriate relationships set.

[image]